# C++ - Access violation reading location while reading .tga file

Tags: c++, file-io

I'm writing a .tga reader. I can read the header perfectly, and after that I would like to read the data part of the file, but if I get there it gives me the error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x76ffa2ce in TGALoader.exe 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xffff0008
```

The length of the file is `65580`, and I read `65536` after the `18 bytes` length header.

My current code is (I cut out the non important part):

```
// Texture variables    
GLint   bitsPP;
GLsizei width;
GLsizei height;
GLubyte *imgData;
/////////////////////////////////////////////////

file.seekg( 0, std::ios::end );
std::cout << file.tellg() << "\n"; // 65580
file.seekg( 0, std::ios::beg );

file.read( ( char* )&tGAHeader, sizeof( tGAHeader ) );

texture->width  = tGAHeader[13] * 256 + tGAHeader[12];
texture->height = tGAHeader[15] * 256 + tGAHeader[14];
texture->bitsPP = tGAHeader[16];

short bytesPP = texture->bitsPP / 8; // 4
unsigned int imgSize = texture->width * texture->height * bytesPP; // 65536

texture->imgData = new GLubyte[imgSize];

file.read( ( char* )&texture->imgData, imgSize ); // Access violation reading location
```

I can't imagine what can be a problem, so I hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
file.read( ( char* )&texture->imgData, imgSize )
```

by

```
file.read( ( char* )texture->imgData, imgSize )
```

`texture->imgData` is just a pointer, don't use it a second indirection level

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried almost everything, but I never thought, that this could be the problem.